# unit testing of AngularJS code deployed under JBoss 7.1EAP

Tags: angularjs, jboss7.x

We all know that one of the best combination for Unit testing for AngularJS code is NodeJS, Jasmine and Karma js framework .

However challenge with our project is that client doesn’t want to use two containers i.e. NodeJS for testing and Jboss for deployment. Reason is the way Angular JS components are packaged for nodeJS is very different from Jboss. Also another angle to this problem is that angular components should be tested in a continuous integration environment. If you have two containers it makes whole CI/CD cycle complex.

Hence we are trying to find out a way on to how to execute these unit test cases with only Jasmine with JBoss 7.1EAP. And without using Nodes and Karma.

Please let us know if someone has faced this issue and let us know the steps for the resolution.

Regards
Debashish